# MySQL indexing optimization

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have following table  - 'element'

```
CREATE TABLE `element` (
  `eid` bigint(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `depth` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classes` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `webarchiver_uniqueid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowstatus` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'A',
  PRIMARY KEY (`eid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12090 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Column details and current index details are given above. Almost 90% of queries on this table are like:

```
select * from element 
    where tag_name = 'XXX'  
    and text = 'YYYY'  
    and depth = 20  
    and classes = 'ZZZZZ'  
    and rowstatus = 'A'
```

What would be the most optimal way to create index on this table? The table has around 60k rows.

Comment: how about a composite index on (tag_name,text,depth,classes) ... if you are not happy then a full refund

Comment: can we lose the picture by merely doing a `show create table element` .. so you have 8500 rows. ok. hard to read (sure I can click on it). But I mean decipher. Or leave it and give us the text

Comment: Thanks. If I use `CREATE INDEX element_search ON element(tag_name,TEXT,classes,rowstatus);` I am getting this error: `BLOB/TEXT column 'TEXT' used in key specification without a key length.` What would be the solution to this?

Comment: i was wondering if you really need a TEXT

Comment: `text` is NOT a good choice of column name as it is a reserved word. you will regret it

Comment: @Used_By_Already sure, I will change it.

Comment: text is not a reserved word in the way that int is. You don't even need to escape it in mysql

Comment: nothing wrong with this: `create table x (id int not null, text int not null ); insert x(id,text) values (1,1);`   .... should you, no, but it is not a reserved word. It's a Keyword

Answer (score 0):

Change `classes` from `TINYTEXT` to `VARCHAR(255)` (or some more reasonable size), then have

```
INDEX(tag_name, depth, classes)
```

with the columns in any order.  I left out `rowstatus` because it smells like a column that is likely to change.  (Anyway, a flag does not add much to an index.)

You can't include `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns in an index.  And it is not worth it to do a 'prefix' index.

Since a `PRIMARY KEY` *is* a `UNIQUE` key, `DROP INDEX eid_UNIQUE`.

Is there some reason for picking "binary" / "utf8_bin" for all the character fields?

Comment: I think 'utf8_bin' is coming from my tool. I can remove rowstatus also, its not a show-stopper. What will be the solution for TEXT because at times it can have really big text (5000+ characters) although average length will be around 100 ..

Comment: For the column `TEXT` sounds correct.  For the index, the 3 columns I mentioned in the composite index will probably do a good enough job.

Comment: utf8_bin seems to come from the column named "Binary".  The issue is that `A` and `a` are treated as different characters.  Whereas, with utf8_general_ci, they would be treated as equal.  This is _normally_ the correct thing for text.

Comment: There is slight performance improvement. Is there any other design changes I can make to improve performance?

Comment: How long does it take to run now?  How many rows in the output?  Please add the revised `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to your Question.